# Preferred React Native navigation library

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I'm looking for a navigation library for a new React Native project. I've read information on this 3 main libraries:

- react-native-router-flux
- react-native-navigation
- "Standard" react native navigation system

I have read that the "standard" system is very buggy, is it true?
What is your favorite navigation library to date?

Answer (score 1):

The most used navigation library for react is [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) as it is kind of simple to use, has a lot of features and can be customise at will.

**react-native-router-flux** is a wrapper over **react-navigation**, it is really simple to use and allows you to write a lot less code than with **react-navigation**, however if you want to implement complex features it might not be the best choice.

**react-native-navigation** aims to do the same things as **react-navigation** but... misses the point, as it clearly lakes some complex features that **react-navigation** has.

I suggest you to read https://medium.com/@ian.mundy/choosing-a-routing-library-for-react-native-604f97e58729 if you can, although that article is from 2017 it is still relevant !

Answer (score 0):

You should give [the Navigation router](https://grahammendick.github.io/navigation/documentation/native/hello-world.html) a try. It provides 100% native navigation on iOS and Android. It isn’t like React Native Navigation because it doesn’t require any native setup and has a JavaScript array representation of the native stack of screens.